# GCD of {0} in integral domains

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, integral-domain

Quoting Hungerford's *Algebra*:

> A nonzero element $a$ of a commutative ring $R$ is said to **divide** an element $b \in R$ (notation: $a \mid b$) if there exists $x \in R$ such that $ax = b$.
>
> Let $X$ be a nonempty subset of a commutative ring $R$. An element $d \in R$ is a **greatest common divisor** of $X$ provided:
>
> 1. $d \mid a$ for all $a \in X$;
> 2. $c \mid a$ for all $a \in X$ $\implies$ $c \mid d$.

In particular, the greatest common divisor (from now on I use "gcd") of any nonempty subset of a commutative ring $R$ must be a nonzero element of $R$ (else, writing $d \mid a$ would make no sense). Now what's the gcd of $\{0\}$ in an integral domain? Condition 1 is satisfied by every element $d \in R$. In fact, given $d \in R$, we have that $d0 = 0$ for all $d \in R$, hence $d \mid 0$ by definition. What can we deduce from condition 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since every element $c \in R$ satisfies the condition $\forall a \in X:c\vert a $, condition 2 tells us that $d \in R$ needs to be an element such that $\forall c \in R: c \vert d$. There exists only one such element in $R$.

<s>Also, the first statement after the definition is false. In fact, it is precisely what answers your question.</s>

According to the definition of Hungerford, a GCD of a subset is indeed defined to be non-zero since a divisor is defined to be non-zero. That given, it is sensible to simply define the GCD of $\{0\}$ as $0$. Note, however, that the definition varies among authors as is also mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_(ring_theory)#Zero_as_a_divisor,_and_zero_divisors).

Comment: The first statement after the definition is false. Why? By definition the gcd divides every element of $X$, thus by the previous definition the gcd must be a nonzero element. Where am I wrong?

Comment: @Lele99_DD The nonempty subset $\{0\}$ is precisely the only exception for that statement. In that case $d \vert a$ i.e. $0 \vert 0$ makes sense since $1 \cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: So the solution is that the definition provided by Hungerford works for every nonempty subset $X \neq \{0\}$, whereas we define the greatest common divisor of $\{0\}$ to be $0$? Just a matter of definitions?

Comment: @Lele99_DD No,no, it's not a matter of definition. The GCD of $\{0\}$ is not defined to be $0$ - there is a proof for it: 1. $\forall a \in X: 0 \vert a$ since $0 \vert 0$ since there exists a $c \in R$ such that $c\cdot 0 = 0$ for examples $c = 1$. 2. for any $c \in R$ s.t. $c \vert 0$ (which is true for any $c \in R$) we have $c \vert 0$ since $0 \cdot c = 0$. Hence $0$ is the GCD of $\{0\}$.

Comment: Following Hungerford's definition of divisibility, writing $0 \mid a$ makes no sense because "a nonzero element $a$ of a commutative ring $R$ is said to divide". I guess what you're trying to say is true only if we use different definitions and I'd prefer to stick with Hungerford's.

Comment: @Lele99_DD Ah yes, I didn't catch, my mistake. Yes, if Hungerfords definition is used, then one has to define $0$ to be the GCD of $\{0\}$.